# GStreamer tutorial for Android Studio

Tags: android, android-ndk, gstreamer

I'm trying to use [GStreamer](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/index.html), but their tutorials seems to be broken (or made for Eclipse). So I'm trying to run this **gst-player** from [here](https://github.com/sdroege/gst-player). I have loaded this project in to the Android Studio. Have included `gstAndroidRoot=D\:\\Packages\\gstreamer` in the `gradle.properties`.

`local.properties` file contains the path to the SDK and NDK like below:

```
ndk.dir=D\:\\Android\\sdk\\ndk-bundle
sdk.dir=D\:\\Android\\sdk
```

I have downloaded the gstreamer code from [here](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/pkg/android/1.12.0) (which is universal for all the architectures). I have set the environment variable `GSTREAMER_ROOT_ANDROID` in my windows development machine where I have extracted the above source codes.

Question 1: Android Studio couldn't able to understand the gstreamer location. It is giving error in `package org.freedesktop.gstreamer.play;` in the `gst_player\app\src\main\java\org\freedesktop\gstreamer\player\Play.java` file.
How could I link the gstreamer source code to Android Studio? As I have already set the environment variable and set the `gstAndroidRoot` in the gradle properties, what else do i have to do?

Question 2: Do i have to compile those `.so` files?
In this [link](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/installing/for-android-development.html#building-the-tutorials), they have mentioned about building the source for creating android specific `.so` files. But when i run `android update project -p . -s --target X` from the tutorial folder, it says 'android' is not a command. I could see that `android.bat` is part of the android sdk (D:\Android\sdk\tools). But even then, executing android.bat doesn't provide `update project` options.

Question 3: How could i build the `libgstreamer_android.so` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

these tutorials are really not made for Android Studio but I was able to make them work and I already answer one question on how to make it work at link: [Gstreamer examples in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45044210/gstreamer-examples-in-android-studio/46223465#46223465)
You could also try to set the variable GSTREAMER_ROOT_ANDROID at Android.mk file... Take a look at step 3 from the link typed above.

Answering 1: Maybe it's a similar problem I had at step 5 from the Question from the link above. Take a look there, perhaps it will help.

Answering 2: I'm not sure, but I think you don't need to compile .so...

In the link I typed above there's also a project from the Tutorial 5 already set to work if Android Studio (but it was made in Linux)... Maybe it could also help you.