# GStreamer Android SDK error for tutorial-5

Tags: android, c++, android-studio

We have taken clone of a [project](https://github.com/jaroslavas/Gstreamer-Android-example) and made all settings as per instruction still not able to build app due to following error:
Error:(7, 10) fatal error: 'gst/gst.h' file not found

above error is in tutorial.c file:

```
#include <gst/gst.h>
#include <gst/video/video.h>
#include <gst/video/videooverlay.h>
#include <pthread.h>

GST_DEBUG_CATEGORY_STATIC (debug_category);
#define GST_CAT_DEFAULT debug_category
```

Please find below gradle and Android.mk file which I have added to my project:
Gradle

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
defaultConfig {
applicationId "com.example.ndktest"
minSdkVersion 19
targetSdkVersion 22
versionCode 1
versionName "1.0"
testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
externalNativeBuild {
cmake {
cppFlags "-frtti -fexceptions"
arguments '-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang',
'-DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-19',
'-DANDROID_STL=gnustl_static',
'-DANDROID_ARM_NEON=TRUE',
'-DANDROID_CPP_FEATURES=exceptions rtti'

        }
    }
    ndk {
        moduleName "tutorial-5"
    }
}

sourceSets.main {
    jni.srcDirs = []
    jniLibs.srcDir new File(buildDir, 'lib')

}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        path "CMakeLists.txt"
    }
}
}
```

Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

GSTREAMER_ROOT_ANDROID := D:\ndk-gst1.9.1

SHELL := PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin /bin/bash

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := tutorial-5
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := tutorial-5.c
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := gstreamer_android
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog -landroid
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

ifndef GSTREAMER_ROOT
ifndef GSTREAMER_ROOT_ANDROID
$(error GSTREAMER_ROOT_ANDROID is not defined!)
endif
GSTREAMER_ROOT := $(GSTREAMER_ROOT_ANDROID)
endif
GSTREAMER_NDK_BUILD_PATH := $(GSTREAMER_ROOT)/share/gst-android/ndk-build

include $(GSTREAMER_NDK_BUILD_PATH)/plugins.mk
GSTREAMER_PLUGINS := $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_CORE) $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_PLAYBACK) $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_CODECS) $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_NET) $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_SYS) $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_CODECS_RESTRICTED)
G_IO_MODULES := gnutls
GSTREAMER_EXTRA_DEPS := gstreamer-video-1.0

include $(GSTREAMER_NDK_BUILD_PATH)/gstreamer-1.0.mk
```

Please suggest what changes need to be done in above code to make it run.

Answer (score 0):

I already answered a similar question... The problem with the official tutorials from the Gstreamer site is that they are old and made for Eclipse. Maybe your error is because you didn't link your Android Studio project to the C++ files... to do it follow the **second** step from this answer:  [Gstreamer examples in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45044210/gstreamer-examples-in-android-studio/46223465#46223465) 
Since the linking with C++ files ins't the only error that will occurs I also suggest that you follow all other steps. There's a link for gitlab project with "turorial 5" working in the link above.